# Horizontal Collection view on UI table view cell Reusing The collection view data for next row

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

[Section 0 Horizontal collection view cell[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H7wl.png)Hi i am using Horizontal collection view On Custom UI table view with Sections  Everting Looks fine till the Fist Section .The Problem is Collection view On section 2 indexpath.row 2 is showing the section 1 first index data .Please Help me Out of this .I am sharing the images how it display the same cell

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a reuse cell problem.

You can try below method first to make sure it is reuse problem:
Replace your reuse cell code in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```c
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourCellIdentifier"];
```

TO:

```c
NSArray *nibObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCellNibName" owner:nil options:nil];
if(nibObjs)
  cell = [nibObjs objectAtIndex:0];
```

If the codes fix your problem, it means this is really a reuse cell problem. You can search some reuse cell guides to read.